# In VBscript a function is supposed to read through a file but it sometimes starts at the end and sometimes at the top?

Tags: vbscript

The code is supposed to read through a file from top down and it is but sometimes it reads it from the bottom up.

I want it to read from the top down, is there a way of telling it to just read from the top?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
'Read lines
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
Lineg = objFile.ReadLine
Lineh = objFile.ReadLine
Linei = objFile.ReadLine
Linea = objFile.ReadLine
Lineb = objFile.ReadLine
Linec = objFile.ReadLine
Lined = objFile.ReadLine
Linee = objFile.ReadLine
Linef = objFile.ReadLine
```

This is after opening the file and all that is needed at the top. And the `Do Until` is closed after this.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify? I'm not sure what you mean. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that will work in both vbscript and Excel VBA:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim oFSO
    Dim arrLines
    Dim i

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    arrLines = Split(oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Test\test.txt").ReadAll, vbCrLf)

    For i = LBound(arrLines) To UBound(arrLines)
        MsgBox arrLines(i)
    Next

    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Erase arrLines

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your code, it works brilliantly, not quite right for my file but your code will do the job for anyone else who has this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry that it is not quite right for your file.  I hope you can adapt it to suit your needs.  If you are having trouble doing so, please post back with what is not working and what your needs are so that we can assist you.

Answer (score 1):

The TextStream reads a file sequentially; each .ReadLine will get the next line - top to bottom - from the file. So "sometimes it reads it from the bottom up and sometimes it reads from the top down" is just not possible.

**Update wrt comment:**

1. It's not possible, that a .ReadLine gets line i from the file and
   the next .ReadLine get a line j with j <= i; if the is a next line, it will be j = (i+1) (of course you can use variable names that make it easy to mis-interpret the reading order)
2. If a .ReadLine gets the last line, the were enough .ReadLines (or .SkipLines) executed before to reach that line

Comment: Well, in this file it is reading sequentially but it starts on the last line and then goes up from there but that just produces an error.